# FB Like button in emails?

Tags: facebook

Does the FB Like button work in email newsletters? Or will this only be used for a website?

A friend was asking me if you can put these in an email, and like the email (putting any URL in of course) will it work correctly as it would on a website? Would the information be updated if Person A opened email, liked the email, then Person B opened up the same email on another system will they see the increase in the total number of people liking it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Non-FBML like buttons are implemented via iframes, and as such won't work in emails since there's not a self-respecting email client in the world that will render an iframe in an HTML email.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be to just embed a link to a like button, that appears as a standard fb "like" in the email. It's a 2-click process but is potentially less confusing for some users than just redirecting to a facebook page.
Here's the code:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR-URL-HERE&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35&amp;appId=123999054357802" target="_blank">
<img src="YOUR-SITE/images/fb_like_button.png" border="0" style="vertical-align:middle;" /></a>
```

All you need to do is replace the YOUR-URL-HERE parts with your facebook page URL, and the YOUR-SITE part with a URL to a facebook like button image.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried a few times to launch email campaigns with dynamic elements like video or widgets. It never works. You can put a static image and link it but that's about it.

The reason for that is rather simple - while the email editors are giving an HTML based editor to write the email the end result is not really running in a browser (think outlook) and when it does it's inside an email web application (like gmail) that blocks all dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can add a Facebook Like button and/or a Tweet Button. Please Note: Where it says my-campaign-url.com  is the webpage of the email newsletter. Replace `img src` with your own image for the button. Also I am not sure you need everything in the Facebook button but you can clean it up with some testing =>

**Facebook Like**

```
<a title="Like this on Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.
php?href=http://my-campaign-url.com&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=
false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=427%20">
<img src="/Images/network_icons/fblike-button-small.png" style="border: 
0 none;" alt="Like This on Facebook">
```

**Tweet Button**

```
<a title="Share Via Twitter" href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?
url=http://my-campaign-url&amp;text=My%20Text%20-%20&amp;via=My Name&amp;">
<img src="/Images/network_icons/tweet-button-small.png" 
style="border:0 none;" alt="Share Via Twitter">
```